# ValidationException error when deploying AWS WorkSpaces via terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I've been trying to deploy AWS WorkSpaces infrastructure using Terraform. The code itself passes the verify and plan check, but it fails to apply.

Source:

```
module "networking" {
  source = "../../modules/networking"
  region = var.region
  main_cidr_block = var.main_cidr_block
  cidr_block_1 = var.cidr_block_1
  cidr_block_2 = var.cidr_block_2
  size = var.size
}

resource "aws_directory_service_directory" "main" {
  name     = var.aws_ds_name
  password = var.aws_ds_passwd
  size     = var.size
  type = "SimpleAD"
  vpc_settings {
    vpc_id     = module.networking.main_vpc
    subnet_ids = ["${module.networking.private-0}", "${module.networking.private-1}"]
  }
}

resource "aws_workspaces_directory" "main" {
  directory_id = aws_directory_service_directory.main.id
  subnet_ids   = ["${module.networking.private-0}", "${module.networking.private-1}"]
}

resource "aws_workspaces_ip_group" "main" {
  name        = "Contractors."
  description = "Main IP access control group"


  rules {
    source      = "10.0.0.0/16"
    description = "Contractors"
  }
}
```

Error code:

```
ValidationException: 2 validation errors detected: Value at 'password' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: (?=^.{8,64}$)((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9\s])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9\s])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9\s]))^.*; Value '' at 'name' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[\\.-])+([a-zA-Z0-9])+$
        status code: 400, request id: 073f6e61-775e-4ff9-a88e-e1eab97f8519

  on modules/workspaces/workspaces.tf line 10, in resource "aws_directory_service_directory" "main":
  10: resource "aws_directory_service_directory" "main" {
```

I am aware that it is a regex issue with the username/passwords, but I haven't set any users for now, and I've reset the security policies for testing reasons.

Anyone had this issue before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [AWS API for the directory service enforces a constraint on the `password` attribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/devguide/API_CreateDirectory.html#API_CreateDirectory_RequestSyntax) and matches what you are seeing in that error when you run `terraform apply`:

> **Password**
>
> The password for the directory administrator. The directory creation
>   process creates a directory administrator account with the user name
>   Administrator and this password.
>
> If you need to change the password for the administrator account, you
>   can use the ResetUserPassword API call.
>
> Type: String
>
> Pattern:
>
> ```
> (?=^.{8,64}$)((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9\s])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9\s])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9\s]))^.*
> ```
>
> Required: Yes

Normally Terraform is able to validate this with the plan or validate commands but unfortunately the AWS provider is [currently missing an appropriate `ValidateFunc`](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/a2373c1b81023e2b3c329905bb0f409c6d63c540/aws/resource_aws_directory_service_directory.go#L32-L37) so it will only fail at apply time instead at the minute.

If you want this to be caught at plan or validate time then you should raise a feature request for it on the [provider issue tracker](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues).

Comment: Okay, so that explains that.

Comment: However, a question still remains - how can I fix this/what format of data should I include? I tried inputting various combinations, and none have worked so far.

Comment: You need to enter a password that matches that overly complex regex. At a glance it boils down to be between 8 and 64 characters and contain a letter, a number and a punctuation character. You can test things [here](https://regex101.com/r/eDFPO8/2).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I know it may have sounded like a rookie question, but thanks for helping me solve it anyways.

Had no idea that API had a SECOND password enforcement policy, other than the IAM one.

Comment: Not a rookie question at all. Ideally Terraform would have caught it at the plan or validate time and tends to do so but it requires someone to add the restriction to a ValidateFunc and these aren't always done by the contributor. If you raise a feature request on the issue tracker then hopefully someone will get around to it at some point as it's a simple addition. Alternatively, if you're interested, then it makes for an easy way to start contributing back to Terraform and learning how it works.

Comment: Okay, I got excited too early. Even it it DOES match it on the tester, it still is thrown off by AWS on apply.

Comment: And it gets better... While it fails to pass on data input on planning, it works on hard-coded passwords and names. And it sucks.

Comment: That's probably worth raising as a separate question where you show example inputs and how you are inputting them. Remember to include a [mcve] in your question with all the associated errors for specific inputs and show where it does work.

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it!


It was all a matter of proper variable and interpolation syntax placement... Should have placed it in the code above, instead of calling it inside the main modules.tf file.